# CoffeeScript change image src on mouseover

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to have a simple image src updated on a link mouseover using CoffeeScript in a Rails view.

For some reason this works fine:

```
showimghover = (imgpath) ->
  $('.thelink').mouseover ->
    imgpath = '../../images/imagefile.jpg'
    $("#theimage").attr
      src: '../../images/imagefile.jpg'
```

But for some reason this does not update the img src when I plug in the string variable instead of writing the URL by hand:

```
showimghover = (imgpath) ->
  $('.thelink').mouseover ->
    imgpath = '../../images/imagefile.jpg'
    $("#theimage").attr
      src: imgpath
```

EDIT:

To clarify the issue, this works fine:

```
$('#imghover').css('background','url(../../images/imagefile.jpg)')
```

But when a variable is inserted, it does not work:

```
imgpath = 'url(../../images/imagefile.jpg)'
$('#imghover').css('background', imgpath)
```

Comment: can you show us how you're calling the showimghover function?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out... When I move this code out of the "showimghover" function it works. I'll have to reintegrate this code with a function to dynamically set the image path, but my original question is solved.

```
$ ->
    $('.style-link').mouseover ->
        $('#imghover').css('display', 'block')
        imgpath = 'url(../../images/OT153575_CRM_FRONT.jpg)'
        $('#imghover').css('background',imgpath)
```

I still don't understand why this happened, as I am very new to CoffeeScript.